# Some questions on the basics of invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme. A $\mathcal O_X$-module $\mathcal L$ is called invertible if, for every point $x\in X$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an isomorphism of $U$-modules $\mathcal O_X|_U \cong \mathcal L|_U$.

I am struggling with the basics of sheaf theory, and I have the following questions.

$1.$ Why is the tensor product of two invertible sheaves invertible?

$2$. Why is the pullback of an invertible sheaf by a morphism an invertible sheaf?

$3.$ Why is the twist $\mathcal O_X(k)$ on $X=\operatorname{Proj} B$ for a graded ring $B$ invertible, where $k$ is any integer, possibly negative?

I have a few jumbled thoughts.

For $1$, recall that the tensor product of two sheaves takes the presheaf that assigns to an open set $U$ the module $ \mathcal L_1(U) \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X}|_U} \mathcal L_2(U)$ and sheafifies it. If we pick open sets $U_i$ such that 
the sheaf $\mathcal L_i$ is trivialized on $U_i$, then on $U_1\cap U_2$ they both have trivializations, and their tensor product on this open set is isomorphic to 
$\mathcal O_X(U) \otimes_{$\mathcal O_X(U)} \mathcal O_X(U)=\mathcal O_X(U)$, which gives the desired result *on the presheaf*. I do not see why this still holds after sheafificaiton.

For $2$, I tried using the local tensor product definition of the pullback sheaf, but I could not simply it.

For $3$, it suffices to show it for $k=\pm 1$ and use $1$, because $\mathcal O_X(n) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal O_X(m)=\mathcal O_X(n+m)$.

Comment: Just for $3$ based on what you mentioned, you may take $m = -n$.

Comment: @Youngsu What exactly are you showing? I don't understand your remark.

Answer (score 9):

1. It is not enough to argue with sections. You have to consider the whole sheaf! 
   Tensor products commute with restrictions to open subsets. Therefore it is enough to remark that $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_X$.
2. Pullbacks commute with restrictions to open subsets. Therefore it is enough to remark that $f^* \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$ for a morphism $f : Y \to X$.
3. In general we have $\mathcal{O}(n+m) \cong \mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \mathcal{O}(m)$. You can find this in every introduction to algebraic geometry (of course the same remark applies to 1. and 2.). In particular, $\mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \mathcal{O}(-n) \cong \mathcal{O}$. Alternatively, $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is freely generated by $f^n$ on $D_+(f)$, where $f \in B_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. Could you please explain in more detail your explanation of $1$? In particular, why does it suffice to show that last equality?

Comment: Oh, this is totally obvious. I forgot the quasi-coherent hypothesis! You are right.

Comment: Ok, I now understand $1$ and $3$. However, I'm still a bit fuzzy on $2$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, this has nothing to do with schemes or quasi-coherence. It holds for ringed spaces in general.

Comment: Let $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ be sheaves. It is my understanding that $(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G)(U)=\mathcal F(U)\otimes \mathcal G(U)$ does not hold in general, but does hold when the sheaves are quasi-coherent. Hence my comment.

Comment: For $2$, I tried using the tensor product definition of the pullback. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism. If $V$ is some affine set on $Y$ where the invertible sheaf is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_X$, and $U$ is open and affine such that $f(U)\subset V$, we have $f^*\mathcal G|_U \cong (\mathcal G(V)\otimes_{\mathcal O_Y(V)} \mathcal O_X(U)^\sim$. I'm not sure how to finish computing this.

Comment: I suppose you don't need the fact that they're quasi-coherent. You can use the fact that sheafification commutes with the restriction to open sets.

Comment: The above tensor product is just $\mathcal O_X (U)$, right? Showing that we have a trivialization on $U$?

Comment: It's not true that in general $\mathcal O_X(n+m)\cong\mathcal O_X(n)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal O_X(m)$. If $B$ is generated by $B_1$ as an $B_0$-algebra, then we have an isomorphism (which is true for $B=A[X_0,\dots,X_n]$)